# Firefox Can't See the CSS/HTM Link in Aptana

Tags: html, css, firefox, hyperlink, preview

Why won't Firefox see the link between the HTML and the CSS when I try to view in Aptana? I've emptied the cache in Firefox, checked that the files are in the same folder, double and triple checked the code structure and placement in the header on the html page and tried Safari as the preview browser. I'm working from the local drive. Firefox and Safari see and read the html page fine, but none of the CSS style attributes are "cascading".

Answer (score 0):

Sounds frustrating but there's always a solution (I guess),

First of all, is the link to the css file correct?

Second, is the link inside the header? Placing the file in the body could influence the result.

Thrid, load the page in firefox, right click on the page and select view page source. Locate the link to your css file and check the absolute path from there (click it and see if your css file is actually there).

Maybe the syntax is wrong, try using href="./style.css" in the stylesheet link.

Hope this helps